# Auto Increment filed not returning value (Not Primary Key) - Spring boot JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

According to my requirement I have field with auto increment & **not a key**. I'm in need of getting the value of that auto increment field after calling repository save().

```
merchantEntity = merchantRepository.save(merchantEntity);
merchantEntity.getMerchId() // returns null
```

But some how im not getting the value of auto increment filed, it returns null.
Here is my Entity Class.

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer merchId;
```

I have tried using several other workarounds such as flushing the entity just after save. But the result is same.

```
        merchantEntity = merchantRepository.saveAndFlush(entity); // still returns null

        merchantEntity = merchantRepository.save(entity);
        merchantRepository.flush();
        MerchantEntity toBeUpdatedMerchantEntity = 
                  merchantRepository.findOne(merchantEntity.getId()); // still returns null
```

Is it possible to achieve what i'm expecting. Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: have you found the soluition? I'm facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get this auto incremented value is to do a refresh of the record.

Because JPA only fetches a primary key because after `EntityManager.persist()` the ID must be set.

So you have to reload the record with `findOne()` or `EntityManager.refresh()`

Comment: Hi Simon, Thanks for the response. I have already tried with findOne() as mentioned in the sample code. It still returns a null. Is this what you suggesting?

merchantEntity = merchantRepository.save(entity);
        merchantRepository.flush();
        MerchantEntity toBeUpdatedMerchantEntity = 
                  merchantRepository.findOne(merchantEntity.getId()); // still returns null

Answer (score 0):

You can add this annotation : @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Generated;

...

@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer merchId;
```